# return value of execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Is the return value of [`sqlite3.execute`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) always self? i.e. can I safely `return some_connection_obj.execute(...)` or use method chaining? I fail to find relevant text in that document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When documentation fails, look into the code (python 3.6.4):

At the _pysqlite_query_execute function end:

```
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        self->rowcount = -1L;
        return NULL;
    } else {
        Py_INCREF(self);
        return (PyObject*)self;
    }
}

PyObject* pysqlite_cursor_execute(pysqlite_Cursor* self, PyObject* args)
{
    return _pysqlite_query_execute(self, 0, args);
}
```

So, unless an error occurred, the method returns self.

However, according to [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) (for DB API 2) return values are not defined, which means you are on your own, and possibly the code you write in that way will not be portable among different DB API 2 implementations. And indeed, according to [psycopg docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#execute) `.execute` returns `None`.

The answer is, one can't safely chain methods in a broader sense, because doing so limits future code reuse possibilities.

Comment: I don't look into code because I think it's implement detail and cannot be rely on. I would avoid use this feature (because lack of doc) anyway, just want to make sure I didn't overlook something.